# iOS Swift - How to move searchBar up when scrolling?

Tags: ios, swift

Here is the screenshot of my view:

[image: screenshot]

Now when the user scrolls up, I need to hide this searchBar. When the user scrolls down, I need to show this searchBar. And also it should be gradual, not just show and hide.

Here are my codes right now inside `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.searchBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (navigationController?.view.bounds.size.width)!, height: 55)
self.searchBar.barStyle = .default
self.searchBar.isTranslucent = false
self.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackground
self.searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
self.searchBar.delegate = self
self.view.addSubview(searchBar)
self.definesPresentationContext = true
```

Also, I set the distance of the tableView to the top to be 55 so that the searchBar does not cover the tableView.

What should I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The usual thing is to have a UISearchController and assign its search bar to the view controller's navigation item's `searchController` property. That causes the search bar to behave as you seem to describe, automatically.

Here's an example from my own code:

```
let src = SearchResultsController(data: self.sections)
let searcher = UISearchController(searchResultsController: src)
searcher.searchResultsUpdater = src
self.navigationItem.searchController = searcher
```